# SimpleCursorAdapter isnt binding data to listView

Tags: android, database, sqlite, textview

How do I bind information from my database to a `TextView`? The ListView Isnt showing the information from the `Cursor`. Do I need to use the adapter I have created?
I'm trying to display the results in TextViews withing the List.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contactform);

        Cursor cursor = getCursor();

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,                                                                                                   //Context
                R.layout.contactform,                                                                                   //xml definintion of each listView item
                cursor,                                                                                                 //Cursor
                new String[] {"FirstName", "LastName", "Phone", "Email"},                                               //Columns to select From
                new int[] {R.id.contact_firstname, R.id.contact_lastname, R.id.contact_phone, R.id.contact_email}       //Object to bind to
                );


    }


    private Cursor getCursor() 
    {           
        String TABLE_NAME = "exampleContacts";
        String[] FROM = {"_id", ""FirstName", "LastName", "Phone", "Email"} ;

        dbManager = new DatabaseManager(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbManager.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, FROM, "ContactID=?", new String[] {PrContactID}, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        return cursor;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it wasnt being mapped to the ListView is because `setListAdapter();` wasnt being used.

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.contactform);
    Cursor cursor = getCursor();

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,                                                                                                   //Context
            R.layout.contactform,                                                                                   //xml definintion of each listView item
            cursor,                                                                                                 //Cursor
            new String[] {"FirstName", "LastName", "Phone", "Email"},                                               //Columns to select From
            new int[] {R.id.contact_firstname, R.id.contact_lastname, R.id.contact_phone, R.id.contact_email}       //Object to bind to
            );

     setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're pulling back a single record.  In that case, you don't need to be using the SimpleCursorAdapter, as that is generally used for assigning multiple records to a ListView.   Why not just grab the info you need and manually set them to your TextView(s)?

Also, you shouldn't need to use a manage cursor.  Just get the values you need and then close the cursor like so:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView01); 

Cursor cursor = db.query("exampleContacts", new String[] {"FirstName", "LastName", "Phone", "Email"}, "ContactID=?", new String[] {PrContactID}, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

String text = cursor.getString(0) + " " + cursor.getString(1) + " "  + cursor.getString(2) + " " + cursor.getString(3);

textView.setText(text);

cursor.close();
```

Sorry for any typos... this code is just for example and hasn't been tested.

Comment: I tried this first off and I get ab IndexOutOfBoundsException which is why I went off the rails with the listActivty, any idea on the exception?  To ellaborate it says "index 0 requested with a size of 0"

Comment: Put a check in to make sure you're getting a record back w/ your query.  Perhaps the ID is wrong.   Log the number of records that are in the cursor.   Also, make sure you're only pulling back the columns you're actually going to use and access them accordingly either through their index or like cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex("FirstName") ).

Comment: I have marked your answer as correct, you did answet the question I asked.  Looks like this error is cause by the PrContactID i'm passing in

Comment: Thank you!  I think may have just up-voted it.  If you meant to mark it as correct, click on the check mark  underneath the vote counts.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've unmarked this question as correct, one of the errors was the variable as you pointed out.  But I was really asking about Listviews.  It was a poor question on my part.  Thanks for your time.